# binary-compatibility with C

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

Does Google protocol buffers are binary-compatibly with C structures?
I mean can I read serialized files from C direct into structs without deserializing?
Or [protobuf-c](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/)
is the only one solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the alignment, endianness and packing of structures on your platform, this may or may not work. You may be lucky with your particular target, but in general you should use proper serialise / deserialise routines.

Answer (score 1):

You should never read/write C structs (as well as any built-in types bigger than `char`) from/into sequential interfaces (like files, pipes or sockets) because of padding and endianness issues. Only serialize them field-by-field and take care of endianness.

Comment: There is no endianness issues because NumPy dtype explicitly specifies  bit order

Comment: Oops, I wrote about NumPy... Yes, you're wright, I probably will have problems with bit orders using Google protocol buffers